# can I Remove "endl" in ( cout<<" "<<endl ) in C++?

Tags: c++

I am beginner at C++, my question is can I remove `endl` the one at the end of `cout` like :

```
cout<<" "<<endl;
```

I don't want return to new line . If I can't remove it, what should I do?

Comment: cout<<" "; just do this

Comment: This is one of those times when you could have just tried it for yourself.

Comment: `std::cout << " " << std::flush;` would be an alternative at the simple removal of `std::endl`.

Answer (score 4):

Elephant in the room: remove the `endl` from the `cout`.

But in case you don't own that code, you could *try* "\033[F", which, if your terminal supports it, moves you to the previous line.

Another possibility would be to redirect the `cout` buffer using `rdbuf` to an `ostream` that you control. You could (i) redirect, (ii) call the function that writes the errant `cout` with the new line and (iii) inspect your `ostream` and write to the original buffer, this time omitting the `endl`. Switch everything back once you're done.

Answer (score 2):

Yes of course you do not need to use `std::endl` every time you use `<<`.  As an example a simple way to print a vector with spaces between the elements would look like:

```
std::vector<int> foo = {1,2,3,4,5};
for (auto e : foo)
    std::cout << e << " ";
```

Here we never use a `endl`.  You cout also just use `\n` at the end of a string literal and that will put a newline in the buffer as well.

```
std::cout << "test\n";
std::cout << "this will be on a new line";
```

Notice that I don't put a newline in the last `cout<<` so if there is anymore output it will start off right after the "e" in "line".

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can remove endl. It is an optional parameter to the << stream operator of which there are many. If you don't include it then a new Carriage Return/Line Feed character will not be output and therefore text will appear on the same line in the output (presumably console).

For example

```
cout << "Hello, World" << endl;
```

would become:

```
cout << "Hello, World";
```

or to make the point another way you could write:

```
cout << "Hello,";
cout << " World";
```

There are lots of other examples out there too, here's one for starters: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/basic_io/

Answer (score 0):

```
cout<<"Your message here.";
```

It's as simple as that. Were you trying to do something like...

`cout<<"Your message here."<<;`     ....? This is wrong as:

The `<<` operator signifies that something comes after the `""` part. You don't have any in this case.